# How to manually change Wordpress permalink from id to page name

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am fixing an old wordpress site that is not to be updated but maintain the same state. It was created in 2012. Over the years the hosting company updated PHP and Wordpress automatically and broke the site.

I need the site to be in it's 2012 state so that everything works well. I have rolled the Wordpress version back to 3.3.1 and have PHP 5.4 running on the site.

Certain functionalities work again on the site which is good. However, the admin panel doesn't work in so much as the admin menu appears but when you click on the tab it is blank on the right hand side. If you know how to fix that, please let me know. Error logging doesn't appear to produce any leads.

My issue is that in rolling back, permalinks have gone back to their ID routing rather than page name routing. I need them to be page name routing but since the admin menu is broken I will have to create some rewrite rule in functions.php to achieve this.

Can someone inform me what to write on this. I am unfamiliar with rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should go without saying, but make sure you have a backup before trying this!

I have not tried this myself, and I'm not sure how much has changed since 3.3.1, but this is what I would do:

1. Locate the **permalink_structure** entry under the **option_name** column of the **wp_options** table.
2. Modify the **option_value** to the structure you want to use. For example `/%postname%/`
3. To flush the permalinks or rewrite rules from your theme, you need to use the `flush_rewrite_rules()` function. Add the function to your functions.php file and refresh a page, then comment it out - you only need run it once.
4. Confirm the `.htaccess` rewrite rules are in place:

> ```
> # BEGIN WordPress
>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
>
> # END WordPress
> ```

And hopefully, that should be it!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I managed to actually avoid needing to implement a solution. Marking as answer for thank you.